# Convert to UIImage PNG format interlaced

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible convert an`NSData *dataImage` witch was a format jpeg or png and convert it to PNG interlaced? i know about compression image `UIImagePNGRepresentation` but i think it convert just to non-interlaced PNG. So, how should i set option for an UIImage or NSData to interlaced PNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIImagePNGRepresentation` makes only non-interlaced png.
Nice question, but i think it is impossible using UIKit.

I think you should use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html) to create interlaced png.

---

Look at this [article](http://ironalbatross.net/wiki/index.php5?title=CPP_LIBPNG) , there you can find *Minimal Example of writing a PNG File*

When you set png header in this method

```
png_set_IHDR(png_ptr, info_ptr, width, height,
            bit_depth, color_type, PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
            PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_BASE, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_BASE);
```

try to change `PNG_INTERLACE_NONE` to `PNG_INTERLACE_ADAM7_PASSES`

Comment: humm..i'm studying how to use that now, but its a little difficult. I thought it was more easy but i was wrong =/. Do you have any example how to compress interlaced with this lib? thank you for answer @George

Comment: I have no experience in writing especially interlaced png, but i updated the answer.

Comment: i will try this code. I appreciated your help. Regards @Geoge